# Need help to make pytesseract could choose folder to save

Tags: pdf, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I need help to make the pytesseract could select or choose folder or location to save the outputt result.

This is the code that I use

```
from tkinter import filedialog
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"


def extract():
    files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="Select Images")
    text = []
    n = len(files)
    for i in range(0,n):
        img = Image.open(files[i])
        text.append(tess.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, lang='nld', config='--psm 11 --oem 3'))
        text_files = open(f'test{i+1}.pdf',"+wb")
        text_files.write(text[i])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    extract()
```

I don't have python background but eager to learn more.
Thanks

I have try few code but still not working.
Even better if someone could write and add the code to make it works

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: The code Is not error, the code is working but I need to add code to make possible to select forder where to save the output. Is that possible? since from the code I could select  the document that will be processed.